# URL decoding a string

Tags: 2013, list

I am retrieving data from a SharePoint list, and the results are displayed as follows:

"He would say*&#160*;I can juggle multiple work to meet deadlines"

How can I remove the &160?

Comment: How are you retrieving the data? Post relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JavaScript you can do as

```
var str = "He would say &#160;I can juggle multiple work to meet deadlines";
str = str.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function (m, n) { return String.fromCharCode(n); });
alert(str);
```

Using C# you can do as

```
string mytext = "He would say &#160;I can juggle multiple work to meet deadlines";
mytext = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(mytext);
```

Comment: I was doing it in C#, but figured I could also use the HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() method! Thanks!